# which one is the best method to eliminate the outliers from a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dataset, outliers

I want to find and remove the outliers from a dataset. I detected the outliers using the IQR method and showed them using boxplot,but unable to remove them.

Please suggest any solution.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link:

https://medium.com/@prashant.nair2050/hands-on-outlier-detection-and-treatment-in-python-using-1-5-iqr-rule-f9ff1961a414

Here they have detected the outlier using IQR method & then dropped that particular outlier sample using the below sample code.

```
sample.drop(sample[ (sample.Salary > u) | (sample.Salary < l) ].index , inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

once you are able to find 2 extremes(the thresholds after which values are not needed)
you can simply do this
here left extreme is 5 right extreme is 10,000

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'values':[1277,1854,9132,1277,1853,9332,1854,2561,9132,5143,11111,3]})
    values
0   1277
1   1854
2   9132
3   1277
4   1853
5   9332
6   1854
7   2561
8   9132
9   5143
10  11111
11  3

df2[(df2>5) & (df2.values <10000)].dropna()


    values
0   1277.0
1   1854.0
2   9132.0
3   1277.0
4   1853.0
5   9332.0
6   1854.0
7   2561.0
8   9132.0
9   5143.0
```